# Optimizar una consulta relacionada en sql server inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Muy buenas hice un select con inner join ,pero repito 2 veces la misma tabla **Empresa** yo quisiera saber si  hay un método para no repetir dicha tabla les dejo el ejemplo
mas las tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT EMPRESA = E.DESCRIPCION, EMPRESA_CONTRATA=EC.DESCRIPCION,NUM_COTIZACION,FECHA,P.NOM_PERSONA,ASUNTO,FG.FORMA_PAGO,GARANTIA FROM T_PRO_COTIZACION C
inner join T_PRO_EMPRESA E  on C.ID_EMPRESA=E.ID_EMPRESA inner join T_SEG_PERSONA P on C.ID_PERSONA=P.ID_PERSONA
inner join T_PRO_FORMA_PAGO FG on C.ID_FORMA_PAGO=Fg.ID_FORMA_PAGO  inner join T_PRO_EMPRESA EC on C.ID_EMPRESA_CONTRATA = EC.ID_EMPRESA
```

Aqui otra imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--  En si esta bien mi consulta pero como les digo quiera que tenga solo una tabla en ves de 2 si es que se puede **Gracias por su atención**

Comment: Lo siento no me termina de quedar claro el por que de la existencia de 2 `id` asumiendo que esos 2 hacen referencia a la llave primaria de la misma tabla `Empresas`

Comment: Así es  solo que quiero no repetir la misma tabla empresas en el innee join

Comment: Entonces a lo que entiendo esas laves foráneas `id_empresa` e `id_empresa_cont` guardan valores de la misma tabla empresa no?

Comment: Si maestro pero en esa parte de las columnas no tengo problema

Answer (score 0):

No, asi como lo tienes esta bien ya que estas haciendo llamados a 2 empresas diferentes por ende son 2 tablas aunque sea la misma, si solo quieres usar 1 tabla no te traera datos ya que no va a coincidir una empresa con 2 ID.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia 